# Why I can not install gdm3

Tags: 18.04, gdm

unfortunately I deleted gdm3.
So I want reinstall it again but when I try to install it I see this message.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gdm3 : Depends: libgdm1 (= 3.28.0-0ubuntu1) but 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 
is to be installed
    Depends: gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (= 3.28.0-0ubuntu1) but 3.28.3- 
 0ubuntu18.04.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any one know what is the problem?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` before trying to (re)install ?

Comment: I'd also `sudo apt -f install` too, but it looks like you could have an architecture mix-up (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gir1.2-gdm-1.0 , https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gdm3) but given I don't know your architecture - I cannot be sure.

Comment: I run both of these commands but dose not work for me

Comment: try running `sudo apt install libgdm1 gir1.2-gdm-1.0`

Comment: one of the reasons why windows is better for me

Comment: did anyone fix this?